# ExtJS - How to create a reusable function to avoid code redundancy?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Instead of rewriting massive block of code, I'm trying to incorporate global function into my work but I'm having trouble making it work.

**Explanation:-**

This is what the below code explains, while user clicks on menu item a new tab need to be created inside the tabpanel xtype component.So every time while I'm creating a new menu just copying the click function definition one more time(obviously with the it respective view name inside Ext.create function).

**Program Code:-**

```
     menu:[
            {
                text:'Menu1',
                listeners:{
                    click: function(c){
                        var nodeText = c.text,
                        tabs = Ext.getCmp('app-tab'),
                        tabBar = tabs.getTabBar(),
                        tabIndex;
                        for(var i = 0; i < tabBar.items.length; i++) {
                            if (tabBar.items.get(i).getText() === nodeText) {
                            tabIndex = i;
                            }
                        }    
                        if (Ext.isEmpty(tabIndex)) {                        
                        tabs.add(Ext.create('DemoApp.view.view1',{title:c.text,overflowY: 'scroll',closable:true}));
                        tabIndex = tabBar.items.length - 1;
                       }
                        tabs.setActiveTab(tabIndex);
                    }
                }
            },{
                text:'Menu2',
                listeners:{
                    click: function(c){
                        var nodeText = c.text,
                        tabs = Ext.getCmp('app-tab'),
                        tabBar = tabs.getTabBar(),
                        tabIndex;
                        for(var i = 0; i < tabBar.items.length; i++) {
                            if (tabBar.items.get(i).getText() === nodeText) {
                            tabIndex = i;
                            }
                        }    
                        if (Ext.isEmpty(tabIndex)) {                        
                        tabs.add(Ext.create('DemoApp.view.view2',{title:c.text,overflowY: 'scroll',closable:true}));
                        tabIndex = tabBar.items.length - 1 ;
                       }
                        tabs.setActiveTab(tabIndex);
                    }
                }                    
            }]
```

I just want call something like below while click event happens:

```
 click : createTab("DemoApp.view.view1")
 click : createTab("DemoApp.view.view2")
  //Global function
  view.createTab(function(view){
   // Code
  });
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you're calling the function when you do

```
click: createTab();
```

i think what you want it assign a function to click:

```
click: function(){
  createTab("DemoApp.view.view1");
}
```